# java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class A cannot access class sun.net.SocksProxy because module java.base does not export sun.net to unnamed module

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, groovy, java-11, java-17

My app was working fine on Java11, but when I changed it to Java17 I started getting this error.

```
    2022-08-05 09:02:09.323 ERROR 1 --- [      ASYNC-182] .a.i.SimpleAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler : Unexpected exception occurred invoking async method: public void com.freeproxy.sdkservice.services.asyncProxyCheck.async.AsyncProxyCheck.asyncProxyCheck(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,int,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.freeproxy.sdkservice.services.asyncProxyCheck.async.AsyncProxyCheck (in unnamed module @0xd7b1517) cannot access class sun.net.SocksProxy (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export sun.net to unnamed module @0xd7b1517
    at com.freeproxy.sdkservice.services.asyncProxyCheck.async.AsyncProxyCheck.socksProxyCheck(AsyncProxyCheck.groovy:130) ~[classes!/:na]
    at com.freeproxy.sdkservice.services.asyncProxyCheck.async.AsyncProxyCheck.asyncProxyCheck(AsyncProxyCheck.groovy:112) ~[classes!/:na]
    at com.freeproxy.sdkservice.services.asyncProxyCheck.async.AsyncProxyCheck$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$4cf6e456.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes!/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.3.20.jar!/:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:793) ~[spring-aop-5.3.20.jar!/:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.3.20.jar!/:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763) ~[spring-aop-5.3.20.jar!/:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor.lambda$invoke$0(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:115) ~[spring-aop-5.3.20.jar!/:5.3.20]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

This error occurs at runtime in this method when I try to use SocksProxy

```
int socksProxyCheck(String proxyIp, int proxyPort, String url, int version, String proxyLogin = null, String proxyPassword = null) {
        try {
            URL webUrl = new URL(url)
            SocksProxy proxy = SocksProxy.create(new InetSocketAddress(proxyIp, proxyPort), version)
            if (proxyLogin && proxyPassword) {
                setAuthentication(proxyLogin, proxyPassword)
            }
            URLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) webUrl.openConnection(proxy)
            con.setRequestMethod("GET")
            con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
            con.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US")
            con.setConnectTimeout(5000)
            con.connect()
            int responseCode = con.responseCode
            con.disconnect()
            return responseCode
        } catch (e) {
        }
        return -1
    }
```

gradle-wrapper.properties file:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-bin.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.0'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'groovy'
//  id 'com.avast.gradle.docker-compose' version '0.7.1'
}

allprojects {

    apply plugin: 'groovy'
    apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
    apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

    group = 'com.free-proxy'
    sourceCompatibility = '17'
    targetCompatibility = '17'
    buildDir = '../build'

    configurations {
        compileOnly {
            extendsFrom annotationProcessor
        }
    }

    dependencies {

        // different dependencies go here
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

}
```

I think that this error occurs due to some configuration changes in Java 17 compared to Java 11, but I don't know how to fix it.
I will be grateful for any help.

Comment: Try adding `--add-exports=java.base/sun.net=ALL-UNNAMED` to the Java command line

Comment: @ThiagoHenriqueHupner, I'm using docker-compose and a jar file to run my app, can I add this command to the docker-compose file or some configuration file in my app?

Comment: I think you can do something like: `environment: - JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS="--add-exports=java.base/sun.net=ALL-UNNAMED"`

Comment: This solved my very similar error:
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox cannot access class sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export sun.net.www.protocol.http to unnamed module @74bf2db7 
The trick was to use the exports for the exact java.base class specified as the error.